# Deleting and Inserting - One excute

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm just deleting a table of 8 million records and I have a new query in which I need to insert the 8 million records again. If I will execute:

```
delete from table

insert into table (...)
```

Is there a problem the can occur? Is the `insert` will be after the all table will be deleted?

Comment: Are there just subtle changes between the records?  have you looked at a `MERGE` instead of delete/insert?  Not enough information to really answer your question  IF in transactional the delete will occur before the insert..  What are you worried about?  it may be slow since you're deleting the records, indexes have to be removed recovery logs generated and the same for insert.

Comment: the statements will execute one after another. However, check to see if you can TRUNCATE the table instead. It has less logging than a delete, and will execute faster. For more info check this link. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/truncate-table-transact-sql

Comment: When doing such things, always copy data first, make sure everything is OK (you have all the data) and then delete the source. If you first delete and than try to insert you'll loose all the data.

Comment: If they are two separate statements (as opposed to two threads running each statement), then the `delete` occurs before the `insert`.

Comment: `deleting a table of 8 million records` <= do you mean you are delete 8 million from a table with potentially more OR do you mean you are delete all records from a table that contains 8 million records? Also how do the inserted records match up to what is deleted? Are these changes? Should you be doing an UPDATE or Merge instead? There is not enough information in this question to create a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should first insert records and then delete if records are same but if records are different then there should be no problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use transaction and this steps more useful because Drop will not keep delete log and TRANSACTION Provides transactional integrity If there is an error

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
INSERT INTO table2
SELECT * FROM table1
DROP TABLE table1
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```